# Diagonalization of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I have to diagonalize the following quadratic form:

$$
Q(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2+2xy+2xz+2xt+2yz
$$

I want to complete the squares, so I observe that the first three terms are the square $(x+y)^2$. Then I sum and subtract the quantities $2x^2$, $2z^2$, $y^2$ and $t^2$. Now, how do I have to continue? Which is the associated matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consume all the terms containing $x$ first ... etc ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x+y+z+t)^2-(y+z+t)^2+(y+z)^2-z^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1&1 \\0 & 1 & 1&1 \\0 & 1& 1&0 \\0&0&1&0 \\\end{pmatrix}^{T}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0&0 \\0 & -1 & 0&0 \\0 & 0& 1&0 \\0&0&0&-1 \\\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1&1 \\0 & 1 & 1&1 \\0 & 1& 1&0 \\0&0&1&0 \\\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1&1 \\1 & 1 & 1&0 \\1 & 1& 0&0 \\1&0&0&0 \\\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: So I put $X=x+y+z+t$, $Y=y+z+t$, $Z=y+z$ and $T=z$ and obtain the matrix with diagonal (1,-1,1,-1), right?

Comment: That's right....

Comment: Isn't the associated matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1&1 \\1 & 1 & 1&0 \\1 & 1& 0&0 \\1&0&0&0 \\\end{pmatrix}$ as obtained without diagonalising?

Comment: @TheWanderer The matrix you are referring to is the diagonal matrix $D$ in $P^TAP=D$ where $P$ is a nonsingular matrix. The associated matrix refers to the matrix $A$ itself which is obtained directly from the given quadratic form.